# Como hacer consultas a una rest api con GraphQL y React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Necesito obtener los datos de dos api rest con GraphQL la segunda url pasarle uno d los datos ontenidos en la primera todo esto para llamar solo lo que nesecito

Segun lo que he visto en documentacion y tutoriales con una api GraphQL Seria algo asi

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  useQuery,
  gql
} from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  query GetExchangeRates {
    rates(currency: "USD") {
      currency
      rate
    }
  }
`;
function ExchangeRates() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EXCHANGE_RATES);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return data.rates.map(({ currency, rate }) => (
    <div key={currency}>
      <p>
        {currency}: {rate}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
      <ExchangeRates />    </div>
  );
}
```

Esto es ganacia en performace ya se llama solo lo que se nesecita

Con una backend seria algo como esto

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");
const typeDefs = gql`
  
  enum CharacterStatus {
    Alive
    Dead
    unknown
  }
  type Character {
    titulo: String
    idImagen: ID
    status: CharacterStatus
    contenido: String
    extracto: String
    imagenes: String
  }


  type Query {
    characters: [Character]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    characters: () => fetchCharacters()
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});



const  fetchCharacters = () => {
  
  return  fetch(urlRestApi)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((post) => {
    const posts = post.map((data) => ({
      titulo: data.title.rendered,
      contenido: data.content.rendered,
      extracto: data.excerpt.rendered,
      idImagen: data.featured_media,
    }));
    const imagePostPromises = posts.map((post) => {
      return fetch(`${urlImage}/${post.idImagen}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((imageData) => ({
          ...post,
          imagenes: imageData.source_url,
        }));
    });
    return Promise.all(imagePostPromises);
  })
  .then((postsWithImages) => {
    const myArray = postsWithImages;
    return myArray
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.error("Error en la promesa ", error);
  })
 
}
```

urlImage y urlRestApi corresponden a mis api rest que no puedo mostrar aca pero en los fetch esta lo que nesecito

Lo que quiero hacer es esta peicion que hago con backend en react como lo hice anteriormente con una api GraphQL Pero no consigo como hacerlo, si alguien sabe se lo agredeciria su ayuda